# Inorder traversal to verify that binary tree is a BST

Tags: binary-search-tree, inorder

I am currently working on a Binary Search Tree project, and I would like to implement an inorder traversal:

```
void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if(root!=NULL) // checking if the root is not null
    {
        inorder(root->left_child); // visiting left child
        printf(" %d ", root->data); // printing data at root
        inorder(root->right_child);// visiting right child
    }
}
```

However, my BST varies between 100000 and 1000000 keys, and as you can imagine, printing them all is not very "handy". Can this inorder function be modified so it only prints "The binary tree is a BST"? I have been trying to implement it but I really can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to *verify* whether a tree is actually a *valid* BST, i.e. its in-order traversal would visit its values in non-decreasing order.

For that you need a different function. Here is how it could be done:

```
int isValidBstHelper(struct node *root, int low, int high) {
    return root == NULL || 
        (root->data >= low && root->data <= high &&
         isValidBstHelper(root->left_child, low, root->data) &&
         isValidBstHelper(root->right_child, root->data, high)); 
}

int isValidBst(struct node *root) {
    return isValidBstHelper(root, INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
}
```

`isValidBst` will return 1 when the tree is a valid BST and 0 when it is not.

To print the result, just call like this:

```
if (isValidBst(root)) {
    printf("The tree is a valid BST");
} else {
    printf("The tree is NOT a valid BST");
}
```

Comment: `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are constants defined in `limits.h` -- you need to `#include <limits.h>`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! If I understood properly the "isValidBstHelper" function, if perhaps the root is equal to NULL, it will return root == NULL?'

Comment: It will always return a boolean (either 0 or 1). In case `root == NULL` then this expression is true, and so 1 will be returned.

Comment: Hi @trincot, I was just reviewing this piece of code and I got a doubt. This part of the the isValidBstHelper: 

**(root->data >= low && root->data <= high &&
         isValidBstHelper(root->left_child, low, root->data) &&
         isValidBstHelper(root->right_child, root->data, high));**

What does it do exaclty?

Comment: does it do perhaps the "In Order Tree Walk"?

Comment: Yes, the first two conditions serve to check that the current node's value is within the accepted range for it to be a valid BST node. If any of these two conditions evaluate to false, then that will be returned (remember that `&&` is a short-circuit operator: as soon as an operand is false, no other operand will be evaluated). If the conditions pass, then a recursive call is made to check that the left subtree is a valid BST within a given range. If that returns true, the same is done for the right subtree.

Comment: thank you very much, basically the first two conditions are the ones that checks the validity of the key and the two recursive functions represents the "In order tree walk" which checks that the nodes are indeed in order.